# how can i check whether the entered password is current password?

Tags: laravel

To change the password, i enter the current password.For the correct password also an error msg will be displayed

public function passwordupdate(Request $request){

```
    $user=user::find(Auth::user()->id);

    $validator=Validator::make($request->all(), [
        //'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6|max:14' 
        'cpassword'=> 'required|confirmed|min:6|max:14'                     
    ]);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['cpassword'=>'Please check the password you given']);
    }else{
        $user->cpassword=bcrypt($request->cpassword);
         $user->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey please mark an answer as correct if there is any

Answer (score 3):

Hash checking https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/hashing

```
if (Hash::check('plain_text_password', $hashedPassword))
{
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;`
2. to check if the old password that was inputed by user you can use `Hash::check()`. This function takes 2 parameters. 
   The first one is the plain string and the second one is the hashed password(old password).

You can retrieve old password by `Auth::user()->password` so you if condition would be

```
if(Hash::check($request['oldpass'], $user->password)){
    //insert the new password
    Auth::user->update([
    'password'=>bcrypt($data['newpass'])
    ]);
    Auth::user->save();
}
```

P.S
`Hash::check()` return true or false

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`Hash::check()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/hashing#basic-usage) method. For example, if you want to compare entered password with current user's one:

```
if (Hash::check($request->password, auth()->user()->password) {
    // Entered password is correct.
```